# App script to check the drive storage of all users in the domain on daily basis

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google App Script, but I have a requirement to create an App script to check the drive storage of all users in the domain on daily basis and trigger a notification if the storage exceeds 20 GB. I checked so many links but I didn't find any solution. All of them are showing not relevant to me. Can anyone provide a good reference or any idea? It will be a great help.

**Here is my code**

```
function myFunction() {

 var email = 'xxx@domain.net';
 var subject ="Storage Issue";
 var body = "You have crossed the storage limit";
}

function setStorageTrigger() {
  ScriptApp
    .newTrigger('storagefunc')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .create()
}

function storagefunc(){
 var storage = DriveApp.getStorageUsed();

 if (storage>7.51311111E8)
 {
   MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);
 }
}
```

Here I need to send emails to all users in the domain.

Comment: What did you try till now? Do you have any code you're working on? Your question is too broad as it's currently written. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Since you want to check the storage for all users in your domain, you should authenticate on behalf of all of them. That would require using [a service account with domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority). Are you open to doing that? Are you a domain admin?